# Excel 2013 - Comparing Two Cells

Tags: excel-formula, comparison, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

[image: CLICK ME]

I am comparing two corresponding columns of data. In the first row, it passes because variable A and variable B are in column 2. It does not have to contain the variable starting with C, but it can only be any of the letters contained in cell 1:1. For row three, it does not pass because variable starting with A is not an option within cell 3:1. What conditional formatting would I do for a large data set in **Excel 2013**. That version of excel is all I have available.

Comment: What error do you get when you try the formula from your last question?

Comment: I wasn't even getting an error. It just did not return the correct comparison when I checked a few of them. For example, a cell containing A2 BB1, B2 CC1 when compared to a cell that has B2 CC1, A2 BB1 (in that order) should pass. It works in Excel 2016 but  not 2013. Do you think the version has anything to do with this issue?

Comment: Maybe, did you try the formula in a blank cell and see what it returns?

Comment: It should work in Excel 2013, unless it is on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you had excel 365, it would be much easier. Using 2013, you either have to use `FILTERXML` to isolate the variables, or hard-code for a certain number of variables. Hard-coding gets long very fast.

I can't check in excel 2013, but it would probably look something like this:

```
=SUM(--ISERROR(
    VLOOKUP(
        FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"),
        FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"),
    1,FALSE)
))>0
```

Where the first `FILTERXML` creates an array of variables from cell `B1`, the second from cell `A1`. `VLOOKUP` finds matches for items in column `B` to items in column `A`, and `SUM(--ISERROR(...` counts how many non-matches are found.

For excel 365 it could look like this:

```
=LET(
    Txt_1, $A1,
    Txt_2, $B1,
    Delim, CHAR(10),

    SeqChar1, SEQUENCE(LEN(Txt_1)),
    CharArr1, MID(Txt_1, SeqChar1, 1),
    CharVarStartArr1, FILTER(SeqChar1, IF((CharArr1 = Delim) + (SeqChar1 = 1), TRUE, FALSE)),
    CharVarLenArr1, FILTER(SeqChar1, IF((CharArr1 = Delim) + (SeqChar1 = LEN(Txt_1)), TRUE, FALSE))  - CharVarStartArr1 + 1,
    VarArr1, SUBSTITUTE(MID(Txt_1, CharVarStartArr1, CharVarLenArr1), Delim, ""),

    SeqChar2, SEQUENCE(LEN(Txt_2)),
    CharArr2, MID(Txt_2, SeqChar2, 1),
    CharVarStartArr2, FILTER(SeqChar2, IF((CharArr2 = Delim) + (SeqChar2 = 1), TRUE, FALSE)),
    CharVarLenArr2, FILTER(SeqChar2, IF((CharArr2 = Delim) + (SeqChar2 = LEN(Txt_2)), TRUE, FALSE))  - CharVarStartArr2 + 1,
    VarArr2, SUBSTITUTE(MID(Txt_2, CharVarStartArr2, CharVarLenArr2), Delim, ""),

    OR(IF(ISERROR(XLOOKUP(VarArr2, VarArr1, VarArr1, NA())), TRUE, FALSE))
)
```

`SeqChar1` creates an array of index locations for each string character using `SEQUENCE`.

`CharArr1` creates an array of (single) characters. I'm using `MID` with array `SeqChar1` to output the results as an array.

`CharVarStartArr1` is an array with the starting point of each variable. This is done by getting rid of every position that doesn't correspond to a delim character. I also included the first character or we would be missing the first variable.

`CharVarLenArr2` finds the approximate string length by subtracting the starting index from the index of the next variable. I included the index of the last string character to get the length for the last variable.

`VarArr1` is an array containing each variable. Every variable but the first one also contains the delim character, so I remove them with `SUBSTITUTE`.